# Difference between new Date().valueOf() and new Date() * 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

and

```
new Date() * 1
```

Both give the same value, is there any performance difference? (Just out of curiosity)

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: look the flag "javascript"

Comment: I think there is kind of `toString` method that just acts when you operate with the instance the same way as `.valueOf()` does anyway.

Comment: Javascript + performance? -> [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)  And for this case: [Date getTime, valueOf, +](http://jsperf.com/date-gettime-valueof)

Comment: @Andreas as far as I can tell, `Date.now()` is faster than any of the instance-based approaches. However, it's not supported in IE before IE9, so a simple shim would have to be created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an object in a multiplication expression implicitly involves a call to `.valueOf()` anyway, so there's really no difference at all. That is, the way that the expression

```
new Date() * 1
```

is interpreted involves an attempt to get the operand on the left side of the `*` operator to be a number. That's what the `.valueOf()` method is supposed to do. For Date instances, that returns the millisecond timestamp value.

Note that

```
Date.now()
```

is also equivalent. (Not `new Date().now()`; the "now" function is a property of the Date constructor.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it's for the small code then? :)

Comment: @Prasad the best thing to do, if all you want is the timestamp, is to use `Date.now()`.

Comment: ya as per Andrea's answer, new Date() * 1 is slower than new Date().valueOf() and Date.now(). So, Date.now() is much better!!

Answer (score 3):

as you can see here:

http://jsperf.com/new-date-test-1

the `(new Date()).valueOf` is faster than `new Date() * 1`

looks like the `new Date() * 1` needs to perform an operation to, only after that, call the .valueOf method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool! So, I think it's for small code then!! 

(found it in Google Analytics code) :)

Comment: Your "valueOf" test was missing the function call operator (`()`) - [here is a revised version of the test](http://jsperf.com/new-date-test-1/2).

Comment: Great point.. well.. Date.Now is really faster than others. Anyway, <code>.valueOf</code> is still a better choice (comparing against <code>new Date() * 1</code>).